# Read in 2D array from file in Qt C++

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, combobox

I have a comboBox in a Qt GUI in mainwindow.cpp. I have this text file with a list of emails and employee names like this (this is just an example file):

```
Pete White      pete@mail.com
Jack Peterson   jack@mail.com
Mike Jackson    mike@mail.com
Dave Middleton  dave@mail.com
Sylvester Brown sylvester@mail.com
```

So the ComboBox should display these names but NOT the emails so I guess I could read this file in as a 2D array. (I do know how to do this in C but not in C++ or Qt) And then I only need the first column.

This comboBox is used in a simple form application. So if this form is filled in, it puts these fills in a variable. So like this `Subject = "Soccer"`. All the other inputs worked (like subject) BUT with this one its different. If `Pete White` is selected, it should not be `email = "Pete White"`, but `email = "pete@mail.com"`.

This maybe explained quiet vague but thanks for helping me :) It might help if you guys have something visual:
[image]

*It's Dutch so don't mind the other the text in the image :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify, so I am assuming that this file has fixed-width items, so name is 15 characters long, and the rest of the line is email address.

Now, you want to read the file, split line, create `QPair<String, String>` and put it into the `QList`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QList<QPair<QString, QString> > lst;

    QFile inputFile("addresses.txt");

    if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
       QTextStream in(&inputFile);
       while ( !in.atEnd() )
       {
          QString line = in.readLine();
          // use mid to split line - but you could use QString::split to split on character
          lst.append(qMakePair(line.mid(0, 15).trimmed(), line.mid(15).trimmed()));
       }
    }

    inputFile.close();


    for(int i=0; i< lst.count(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Name: " << qPrintable(lst[i].first) << " Address: " << qPrintable(lst[i].second) << std::endl;
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: now it says that `argc and argv are unreferenced formal parameter`

Comment: Oh, just use `int main()` instead of `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Answer (score 0):

You can read file to QStringList and remove or store email if needed like this:

```
QFile file("path_to_file");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
// reads file, splits it by newline symbol and puts it to qstringlist
QStringList list=QString(file.readAll()).split(QRegExp("[\r\n]"),QString::SkipEmptyParts);
for (int i=0;i<list.count();i++){
    list[i]=list[i].simplified(); // removing unneeded spaces inside string
    list[i].remove(list.at(i).section(" ",-1)); // removing word following the last space, where email is in example
    //(if email is needed, just store it somewhere before removing)
    // list.at(i).section(" ",-1) - email
    // list.at(i).section(" ",0,list.at(i).count()-1) -name and surname
}
file.close();
```

more details about [section is here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#section)